# gluLookAt() makes blank screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glu, perspectivecamera

I don't have much OpenGL experience. I am trying to draw a teapot and move a camera around the teapot. To this end I am using the gluLookAt function. The problem is that when I call gluLookAt the screen is blank and I can't see my teapot.

```
#include "openGLer.h"

void openGLer::simulate(grid* toSim, int* argc, char** argv)
{
    myGrid = toSim;
    glutInit(argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400); //Set the window size
    glutCreateWindow("");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutMainLoop();
}

void openGLer::handleKeypress(unsigned char key, //The key that was pressed
                              int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 27: exit(0);
    }
}

void openGLer::camera()
{
    gluLookAt(3, 3, 0,
              0, 0, 0,
              0, 1, 0
              );
}

void openGLer::draw()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    camera();
    glutWireTeapot(0.5);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void openGLer::display()
{
    draw();
}
```

Why does gluLookAt() make the screen blank and how do I fix this? When camera() is not called code performs as expected; with a teapot being displayed.

Comment: Maybe you're not looking at the teapot?

Comment: Well something like that is happening. But when camera() is not called, then I can see the teapot as expected.

Comment: Because when you don't call `camera()`, you don't change what you're looking at.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you post a change to the code?

Comment: Nah. The OpenGL Red Book already covers all of this with examples, and I don't feel like re-writing it! :)

Comment: @Misha, I think what Tomalak is getting at is that your coordinates in the `camera()` function might be wrong. Perhaps the code works, but it's looking at some random point rather than your teapot. Make sure you're using the right coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set up your projection matrix correctly? Otherwise, your call to `gluLookAt` will cause the teapot to be too far away and therefore be clipped by the far plane.

Try adding this to your initialization code (and also your resize handler to fix the aspect ratio when the window is resized). I've set the far plane at 100, which should be plenty for your teapot.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective (60.0, width/(float)height, 0.1, 100.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to have fixed it!

Comment: Setting up the projection and the viewport should be done in the display function, not the reshape handler.